# How to apply autolayout in nib which is compatible for iphone 5 and iphone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

[image]I have little knowledge of autolayout.We can support for both iphone 4 and iphone 5 designs with autolayout.My view is given below like. I have nib of 4-inch display. I want my nib also compatible with 3.5 inch display. Which constrains i use from nib to set my view perfectly for iphone 4 (3.5 inch) display?
As not much reputation can't upload image so here is explanation of how  my design is :
->i have one image view , then 3 view as shown in image.
->image view size w*h 232*41, first view size 320*161,second view size 320*180,third view size 320*118
->Image view's y is at 25, space between imageview and firstview is 20 ,space between first view and secondview is 8,space between second view and third view is 25.

I have try to apply below constrains
1)For image view
->Pin leading,top and trailing space from superview
2)for first view
->Pin height and pin vertical specing between imageview and first view 
3)for second view
->Pin height and pin vertical specing between first view and second view
4)for third view 
->Pin height and pin vertical specing between second view and third view,also pin bottom space to superview which is 0.
Still my design is messed up for 3.5 inch display.
I try add missing constrains options but still all views messed up. Help me add constarins for each view from nib .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ImageView`.

[image]

For `View1` Note For the Height Constraint Check PlaceHolder `Remove at build time`

[image: View1]

For `View2`

[image]

For `View3`

[image]

Comment: @Pooja Ok please accept the answer if it is right..?